# Featureless Desktop on login

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I'm pretty unfamiliar with Linux, and I've installed Ubuntu 12.04. 
The install seems to have gone smoothly and everything, but I'm having troubles when I log in.

The computer boots up normally and takes me to the login screen, and once I login it takes me to a featureless desktop.  There's no list of programs on the left and no menu bar on the top.  The wallpaper is there, and I get the standard context menu when I right click the background.  I can create folders and search through them and run programs, but everything runs really slowly and windows are pinned in the upper left corner.

I tried logging into a guest account and after about a minute of a black screen with a cursor, it loaded up the normal desktop screen.  Programs are running faster, I can move windows around, I've got my list of programs on the left and my menu bar up top.

Comment: Try to login with the ubuntu 2d option

Comment: Try cleaning some of the dispensable hidden files and directories in your home directory. Sometimes there are things there that get corrupted or are incompatible between versions. Alternatively, try creating a new user for yourself and slowly moving over the things that you need. Let me know if it works.